# Spring data jpa not working with auto configured entityManagerFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am using spring boot and spring data jpa in my application. when i am using autoconfigured `entityManagerFactoryBean` provided by jpa i am getting below error along with the query which is getting generated.

```
  select
        simentity0_.simid as simid1_3_,
        simentity0_.service_number as service_number2_3_,
        simentity0_.sim_number as sim_number3_3_,
        simentity0_.sim_status as sim_status4_3_ 
    from
        sim simentity0_ 
    where
        simentity0_.sim_number=? 
        and simentity0_.service_number=?
2018-11-16 14:26:40.824  WARN 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 904, SQLState: 42000
2018-11-16 14:26:40.824 ERROR 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-00904: "SIMENTITY0_"."SERVICE_NUMBER": invalid identifier
```

But when i provide **explicit configuration** for `entityManagerFactoryBean` using below java configuration.It works fine.

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new 

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            bean.setPackagesToScan("com.mypackage.entity");
            bean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
            bean.setJpaVendorAdapter(getJpaVendor());
            return bean;
        }
```

**Below is the query which is generated when when it is working.**

```
 select simentity0_.simID as simID1_3_,
    simentity0_.serviceNumber as serviceN2_3_, 
    simentity0_.simNumber as simNumbe3_3_, 
    simentity0_.simStatus as simStatu4_3_ 
   from SIM 
    simentity0_ 
   where 
    simentity0_.simNumber=? 
    and simentity0_.serviceNumber=?
```

Here is the Entity Bean and application properties file.

**Application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.username=nawnit.sen
spring.datasource.password=pass
```

**SimEntity .java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SIM")
public class SimEntity {
    @Id
    private Integer simID;
    private Long serviceNumber;
    private Long simNumber;
    private String simStatus;
```

**query.sql**

```
create table SIM (
    simID integer primary key,
    serviceNumber integer not null,
    simNumber integer not null,
    simStatus varchar2(10) not null
);
```

See the `_` in the **column name** in the first query.i don't understand why it is coming in query. Could it be because i have not provided `packageToScan` property  in properties file in first case(where autoConfiguredBean is taken).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `Spring Boot` autoconfiguration uses [SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/orm/jpa/hibernate/SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy.html) but the default `Hibernate` one is [PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl.html)

You can specify the naming strategy you want to use via property, e.g. `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` property

Comment: @NawnitSen, what Spring Boot & Hibernate versions are you using?

Comment: spring-boot-starter-parent 2.1.0.RELEASE and rest are coming from manged dependency version

Comment: @NawnitSen, Try setting `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` and I'll update the answer if it helps

Comment: hibernate-core-5.3.7 and boot -2.1.0. btw "spring.properties.hibernate.namingStrategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy"  this is what i added.

Comment: @NawnitSen, see my comment above